# Minidumps not generated after a bluescreen in Win8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, bios, bsod, minidumps

Lenovo Flex 2-14, windows 8.1 64bit, 4GB RAM, 8SSD-500HDD. All software setup from factory.

The laptop freezes randomly without any pattern and BSOD.

The bluescreen says `kernel_data_inpage_error` and collecting more info is stuck at 0%. It never progresses and I have to hard power down the laptop. After reboot, there are no minidumps generated(minidump is enabled in adv. settings). Sometime the BSOD also gives another additional info in braces (ntoskernal.sys, volmgr.sys, and few other). occurs at least once every one/two day. **Any reason why Minidump is not generated?**

Sometimes the laptop also restarts for no reason and shows up the windows boot manager which does not lists the HDD. **Is it that HDD is not detected and is it related to the above problem?**

The HDD is GPT partioned with UEFI boot enabled. After a lot of factory resets, and even after upgrading to win10, had the BSOD issues.

Someone suggested to change the boot option to legacy. Now I have factory image restored (win8.1) in GPT HDD with leagcy first boot option. I have used the the laptop for a couple of days and the BSOD did not occur till now. Is this a right solution?

Is this a hardware problem because This BSOD occurred in the middle of HDD partitioning after rebooting in AOEMI partition assistant and once while upgrading to win10.(loose cable maybe, but its a brand new laptop and the issue occurred even before putting on any new software) or caused by the boot options?

Comment: "Any reason why a Mini memory dump is not generated?" There are some errors where generating an memory dump is not possible.  I have no idea how you booted a GPT partition HDD in legacy mode, which means you either are not actually using legacy mode or its not actually a GPT partition HDD.

Comment: Boot mode : legacy support, boot priority : legacy first - this is my bios setting

Comment: If that is the case, I find it highly unlikely, your HDD is actually GPT in that case.

Comment: But disk mgmt->disk0 properties-> volumes tab shows its guid partition table

Comment: kernel_data_inpage_error indicates HDD issues. check the HDD for errors.

Comment: I have run scandisk, seatools, memtest several times and did not get any issues reported. Is there any other tool that I can use?